# How to specify a different directory in a snake file

Tags: python, macos, snakemake

This seems like it shouldn't be so difficult but how do I specify a path that is outside of my snake file's working directory for an input? I have a data directory that I want to keep separate and defining it using a relative path is tedious and involves lots of ".."s.

Comment: Would it work to specify an absolute path?

Comment: I get this output: ```Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in rule my_rule in file /path/to/Snakefile, line 1:
Missing input files for rule process_wrz:
    output: path/to/output
    affected files:
        Users/myname/Documents/path/to/input1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the working directory with `--directory DIR, -d DIR`. So can invoke snakemake as `snakemake -d /path/to/data -c 1` .

Comment: Thanks this is a good workaround. Why do you include ```--use-conda``` in your answer?

Comment: Just habit from using conda. I  removed the flag.